# Turning on Bluetooth starts MediaBrowserServiceCompat

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-mediasession, mediabrowserservicecompat

When I turn on bluetooth on my OnePlus, then the `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` starts.

My first logcat entry comes from `onCreate()` method in my class extending `MediaBrowserServiceCompat`. Several other media player apps fire up as well.
There is not much more info in logcat about why and how the Bluetooth fires up the `MediaBrowserServiceCompat`. Thus, I am lost. The behavior is not completely reproducible, but it happens in 9/10 times, especially if my Bluetooth headphones are on. Just connecting the headphones does not result in the same behavior. Only turning the Bluetooth on on the device does.

What causes `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` to start when I turn Bluetooth on or how do I figure what causes it? In turn, how do I prevent such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/mediabuttons#restarting-inactive-mediasessions

> If Android can identify the last active media session, it tries to restart the session by sending an ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON Intent to a manifest-registered component (such as a service or BroadcastReceiver). This lets your app restart playback while its UI is not visible, which is the case for most audio apps.

I think in your case, since your application was the last active MediaSession the system is trying to restart the MediaBrowserService. Try debugging your application by switching to other Media applications (then connect BT) and then check whether the System starts your service or not.

Also, check https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/mediabuttons for more information.

Comment: Multiple apps are started at the same time, not just the last used media app. Furthermore, there is no call to any media button. Also nothing related to `MediaSessionStack` appears in logcat as it does in case of resuming the last active media session via play button.

Comment: If the Android platform(customized by OnePlus) is causing this behaviour, then I am afraid you(as an application developer) cannot do anything to stop this behaviour. You need to handle your business logic in order to achieve the desired result. Btw, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't want my to start my media service just because user turned on bluetooth. From UX POV, the user turns on bluetooth and then media style notification(s) pop up.